# Why does the Shader to RGB node remove Screen Space Reflections?

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, shader-nodes, reflection

Starting with 3.2, any material that includes a Shader to RGB node cannot have Screen Space Reflections, no matter if said node is connected to the shader that actually gives the reflections. This wasn't a problem before, and I don't understand why it got patched. Why was this changed? Are there any workarounds?

3.1.2:
[image: working]
3.2.0:
[image: not working]

Comment: It was probably a bug, try the latest version 3.2.2

Comment: @Emir it's not a bug. here it is in 3.2.2 https://gyazo.com/45a3e9e0c0ec29dd1c6cd614c621925e  its in the patch notes too https://gyazo.com/93b8223ea4c438214885d57b78ce37a1